# Function doesnt Continue after loop when I access child elements

Tags: javascript, loops, children

This is the code I am facing problem for:

### **INSIDE BODY:**

```
    <div id="test">

        <p>Hello World! <b> Some Bold <i> RED(and also Italic)</i>
            </b>
            <i>text</i>
        </p>

        <button onclick="myFunction(this)">Try it</button>

        <p id="demo"></p>

    </div>
```

**INSIDE SCRIPT**

```
    function myFunction(find) {
        var c = find.parentNode.children;
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i <= c.length; i++)
        {
            c[i].children[0].children[0].style.color="red";
        }
          alert("Something in the alert");
    }
```

---

My question is that, why doesn't the

> alert("Something in the alert");

is being executed?

Comment: I've created a snippet for you, in that you get errors on clicking the button. Always include those errors as part of your question.

Comment: check on console if there are any errors, if any add those error logs in question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add check in your code, like this:

```js
 function myFunction(find) {
 var c = find.parentNode.children;
 var i;
 for (i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
  if (c[i].children && c[i].children.length) {
   c[i].children[0].children[0].style.color = "red";
  }
 }
 alert("Something in the alert");
}
```

```html
  
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<body>
    <div id="test">
        <p>Hello World! <b> Some Bold <i> RED(and also Italic)</i>
            </b>
            <i>text</i>
        </p>
        <button onclick="myFunction(this)">Try it</button>
        <p id="demo"></p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the **c[i].children[0] is undefined** . Here javascript stop execution.

So use try catch method to handle such scenario.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
    <div id="test">

        <p>Hello World! <b> Some Bold <i> RED(and also Italic)</i>
            </b>
            <i>text</i>
        </p>

        <button onclick="myFunction(this)">Try it</button>

        <p id="demo"></p>

    </div>

    <script>

    function myFunction(find) {
        var c = find.parentNode.children;
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i <= c.length; i++)
        {
            try {
            c[i].children[0].children[0].style.color="red";
          }
          catch(err) {
          }
        }
          alert("Something in the alert");
    }

    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: However, the code above makes the text red.But how to access childrens of childrens safely (I mean without making the code undefined) ? @Rishab